# How to use & alignment in math-mode with flashcards?

Tags: math-mode, flashcards

So here's my concept:

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Calculus}

\begin{flashcard}[\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{Calculus}}]{Derivation}

\medskip

\textbf{Formula:} 
\begin{align*}
P(x) &= x^2+p\,x+q \\ %this & is causing the problem I assume. 
     &= ...
\end{align*}
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably need `{...}` around the entire `align*`. At least then the example compiled for me.

Comment: Finally worked out, thank you